# Insert HTML Table data to Mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty much new to php and mysql .I am trying to create a php form 
which data will be stored in backend Mysql database

I have created two php files

1. Form.php
2. insert.php

And both these files have an require_once(DB_Login.php) function which 
connects to the Mysql DB

**The contents of Form.php**---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <form action="insert.php"
                  method="POST">
            <?php 
                require_once('DB_Login.php');
                $sql=mysql_query("Select * from Department");
                echo '<table border=1px>';
                echo '<th>DepartmentId</th> <th>Department_Name</th><th> 
                Description</th>';
                $datas=array();
                while($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                    $datas[]=$data;
                    //Running a loop all contents in the Mysql Table
                     echo '<tr>';
                     echo '<td>.$datas[\'Dept_Id\'] </td> <td>.$datas[\'Dname\']</td>
                     <td>.$datas[\'Description\']</td>';
                     echo '</tr>';
                }
                echo'<tr>';
                echo'<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Dept_Id\" id=\"Dept_Id\"></td><td>
                <input type=\"text\" name=\"Dname\" id=\"Dname\"></td> <td><input
                type=\"text\" name=\"Description\" id=\"Description\"></td>';
                echo'</tr>';
                echo '</table>';
                echo'<input type="submit" value="SEND">';
            ?>
            </form>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

**The contents of insert.php--**

```
<?php
    require_once('DB_Login.php');

    $Didtext = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Dept_Id']);
    $Dnametext=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Dname']);
    $Desctext=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Description']);

    echo $Didtext;
    echo $Dnametext;

    $adddept="INSERT INTO Department('Dept_Id','Dname','Description') 

    values('$Didtext','$Dnametext','$Desctext')";
    $result = mysql_query($adddept);
    if($result)
    {
        echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<br>Input data failed");
    }
?>
```

The problem think is values are not being passed to insert.php

```
$Didtext = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Dept_Id']);
$Dnametext=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Dname']);
$Desctext=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Description']);
```

After i run this code I get the message Input data failed.
I did a lot of search for this question .
I am using **id** attribute to pass element value to insert.php

Please help !!!

Comment: For starters, you're not actually using the variables in your SQL statement.  You're using hard-coded strings, and the same ones every time.  Other than that, how exactly is this failing?  What do you mean by "I get the message"?  What isn't working?

Comment: In insert.php I have handled the failure of inserting data in Mysql

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  Understand that we can't debug this for you.  Please perform some debugging and explain exactly what is failing.

Comment: Thank u mohit .Yes i was passing arguments as hardcoded strings instead of variables .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use apostrophe (`'`) when labeling your column names. Remove them.

Your insert query should look like this:

```
$adddept="INSERT INTO Department(Dept_Id, Dname, Description) 
                          VALUES('$Didtext','$Dnametext','$Desctext')";
```

Also, make sure that your `$_POST` values from your form is the same with the `name` HTML tags of your input fields. You don't need to use backslash (`\`) when assigning a name tag on your input fields in your case, where you are using `'` to echo and you are using `"` on assigning HTML tags.

```
<input type="text" name="Dept_Id" id="Dept_Id">
```

And double check the table name and column names that you use in your queries, because these data are case sensitive.

**Note:** You shouldn't be using the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*` API anymore and instead use `mysqli_*` [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Change your **Form.php** code as:

```
...
... 
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="Dept_Id" id="Dept_Id"></td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="Dname" id="Dname"></td>'; 
echo '<td><input type="text" name="Description" id="Description"></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

*No need to write `" \"` before double quotes.*

You did not pass the variables in which you store the value. Do the below change in **insert.php**:

```
$adddept="INSERT INTO Department('Dept_Id','Dname','Description') 
values('".$Didtext."','".$Dnametext."','".$Desctext."')";
```

**NOTE:** If `Dept_Id` is `int` then no need to use `'` before and after the variable `$Didtext`  as :

```
$adddept="INSERT INTO Department('Dept_Id','Dname','Description') 
values(".$Didtext.",'".$Dnametext."','".$Desctext."')";
```

Comment: No .It shows the same error .In insert.php i have even echo $Dnametext            but it does not print the values which i pass from Form.php